# Can't move on to the next page using xmlhttp

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I got stuck at some point creating a parser when it is about going on to the next page. All the pages after the first page give error if link of those pages is clicked in a blank tab , as in the second link provided below. Any help would be a great relief for me. Thanks in advance. Here is the link:

Ist page:
"http://www.sportfocus.com/comdir/keyword.cfm?cid=11&maj=cricket&ckid=102&min=clubs%20and%20Associations&kid=860&key=England"

2nd Page:
"http://www.sportfocus.com/comdir/morekeywords.cfm?cid=11&maj=cricket&ckid=102&min=clubs%20and%20Associations&kid=860&key=England"

Only change noticed is= "keyword" to "morekeywords" in the url

Html element for the next button:

```
<div align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Next 20 Results ->" class="buttonlg">
        </div>
```

Comment: Open the webpage in Chrome, press F12 to open Developer Tools window, click Network tab, then press "Next 20 Results -->" button, and new XHR will appear in the network log, click on it - it is [POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3t4A.png), which form data contains `count` and `rowlimit` parameters. Thus you need to make POST XHR with appropriate `count` and `rowlimit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Omegastripes said, the site requires POST method and two mandatory parameters to be filled in. However, I'm pasting below the code using which I found the full result. It is tested.

```
postdata = "type=Name&rowlimit=200&count=1"
http.Open "Post", "http://www.sportfocus.com/comdir/morekeywords.cfm?cid=11&maj=cricket&ckid=102&min=clubs%20and%20Associations&kid=860&key=England", False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.send postdata
```